# How to make android app in which I can change database after publish the app?

Tags: android, database, real-time

I want to make an application in which I can change the data in realtime after the app publish on play store.

Comment: you can do this..by using a server...place all your data on server..and change it acc to your need

Comment: Can you give me the code example or which library or package i should use???

Comment: Again, which option do you want, the first one, or the second one?

Comment: Here is a very comprehensive way to do it.  http://udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud853

Comment: i want to implement first option

Comment: hey Stephan Branczyk i want to implement first option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a MySQL server, that way you can dynamically edit certain data from inside your app. I recommend you using [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) by Apache for handling the database, it is simple to use with a simple control panel. :)

Here is a tutorial on how to connect and edit a MySQL server on an android device:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_network_connection.htm